# Can't regex on extracted String

Tags: rust, tauri

I'm working on a project using Tauri (Rust Backend/Svelte Frontend). On application start I'm reading every file and its contents in a directory (the users library).

```rust
for file in WalkDir::new("path_to_library")
    .into_iter()
    .filter_map(|file| file.ok()) {
        if file.metadata().unwrap().is_file() {
            let contents = fs::read_to_string(file.path())
                .expect("Should have been able to read the file");
                // extract links from contents (is an object)
                // append to previously extracted links
        }
       // send to frontend
}
```

I'm not at all familiar with Rust and somewhat uncertain on how to proceed now. Ultimately, I need a cleaned up version of the data in my frontend. This involves some Regex and restructuring. However, I ran into problems with Rust being unhappy that my `String` (read from the file) wasn't a `str` when I tried to Regex the files. Should I better do it in the frontend? I was thinking about just creating a JSON with `{"fileName": content}[]`, but it feels like Rust would be much more suitable manipulation tool than JS.

EDIT: The function I wanted to use to extract the `[[...]]` links:

```rust
fn extract_links(text: &str) -> HashSet<&str> {
        lazy_static! {
        static ref LINKS_REGEX : Regex = Regex::new(
                r"/(\[(?:\[??[^\[]*?\]\]))/gm"
            ).unwrap();
    }
        LINKS_REGEX.find_iter(text).map(|mat| mat.as_str()).collect()
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide the compile error? Without it your doubt is unclear. 
But I may guess that you're in troubles with the return value on the HashSet<&str>

Comment: @AlexVergara sure, i get multiple errors: `error[E0425]cannot find value LINKS_REGEX in this scope`, and `error[E0434]: can't capture dynamic environment in a fn item`

Comment: Also, `/re/gm` syntax is not right. Please see examples in the regex crate docs.

Comment: @BurntSushi5 Thanks for pointing that out. I copied the code from [this](https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/rust-cookbook/text/regex.html#extract-a-list-of-unique-hashtags-from-a-text) example now. And I get `error[E0308]: mismatched types` now too.

Comment: Your first error is related with `use` statements. Checkout that you're paths to the code items are correct. 
Second is that you're initializing a `lazy_static` item inside a fn.  So `LINKS_REGEX` are poiting to something that has gone out of scope, even with your static ref there. You should initiaze in a upper or more global scope your static ref, and the access it.

Comment: Add the compiler error detailed for E0308

Comment: The example you linked does not use `/re/gm` syntax, so I'm not sure where you got that from. (I am not saying that this is *the* issue you're facing, but it's certainly one of them.)

Comment: @AlexVergara, BurntSushi5: Your inputs helped me do some basic stuff right and then I was able to follow the rest of the error messages through. So now at least the regex works. Thank you!

Comment: @AlexVergara There is nothing wrong with putting a `lazy_static` inside a function like this. It works just fine: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7a10b7a5eab984936271611ff69947fd

Comment: @MichaBrugger Please provide a playground snippet or similar, as a minimum reproduction of the problem you're facing. The problem is not with the `extract_links` code you've posted, as demonstrated in my prior playground link. The problem is elsewhere, but you aren't showing us the full story.

Comment: @BurntSushi5 I just wanted to point out that `works` doens't mean `the good way to go`.

Comment: @BurntSushi5 With the combined comments from both of you I was able to fix it, so the link extraction works perfectly now. Now I'll have to figure out how to best build a JSON while looping through the library. Once I figured that out I can just send it to the frontend. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @MichaBrugger Good to hear. Please post the answer to your question so that others can benefit. :-)

Comment: @AlexVergara Reducing the scope of a `lazy_static!` by putting it inside a function is absolutely a good way to go! I even recommended it in the regex crate README: https://github.com/rust-lang/regex/#usage-avoid-compiling-the-same-regex-in-a-loop --- That way, it keeps the regex localized to where it's used.

Comment: @BurntSushi5 Done! It's been a series of rather silly mistakes. But I'm happy we figured it out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @BurntSushi5 and @AlexVergara I was able to figure out a series of small mistakes.

First, I had `extract_hashtags` inside `my_czstom_command`. Once I moved it on a higher level, that problem was solved. Second, I did miss the `&` in `let _text = extract_hashtags(&contents);` which let me actually parse my `String` as `str`. And finally, I made a copy error with my regex. Replaced it with `r"\[\[\w*\]\]"` and now it works just fine.

So the whole think looks like this now:

```rust
fn extract_hashtags(text: &str) -> HashSet<&str> {
    lazy_static! {
        static ref HASHTAG_REGEX : Regex = Regex::new(
                r"\[\[\w*\]\]"
            ).unwrap();
    }
    HASHTAG_REGEX.find_iter(text).map(|mat| mat.as_str()).collect()
}

#[tauri::command] // this comes from Tauri
fn my_custom_command() -> String {
    let mut data = ""; // this I still have to figure out, should be a JSON sometime
    for file in WalkDir::new("C:/Users/Micha/Desktop/Mapmind/library/")
        .into_iter()
        .filter_map(|file| file.ok()) {
        if file.metadata().unwrap().is_file() {
            let contents = fs::read_to_string(file.path())
                .expect("Should have been able to read the file");
            let _text = extract_hashtags(&contents);
            // add _text to data here
            
            println!("{}", file.path().display());
            println!("{contents}");
            println!("{:?}", _text)
        }
    }
    data.into()
}
```